# Concatenate a variable into a JSON call with Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm making an API call to coinmarket cap and looping through a range, in a Google spreadsheet of crypto tickers.

The code is as follows:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");
var r = sheet.getRange('B2:B17').getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    symbol = r[i][0];
    url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=' + symbol + '&convert=USD&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=8192e0b9-fda4-4668-9251-3dfded3bdc2f';
    //url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=BTC&convert=USD&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=abcdetc'
    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var result = JSON.parse(resp.getContentText());
    var price = result.data.BTC.quote.USD.price;
    sheet.getRange(2 + i, 3).setValue(price);
```

This works but it provides, obviously, only the price for Bitcoin because BTC is in the var price line.

Instead of BTC I want to have + symbol + so that the code can loop through all the different symbols. I have tried this:

```
var price = result + "." + data + "." + symbol + "." + quote + "." + USD + "." price
```

This does not work. I have tried other various uses of "" which were also unsuccessful and also attempted to concatenate string separately.

How can this be done correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do it in python way, `var price = ".".join([result, data, symbol, quote, USD, price])`. If this does not work, try typecasting explicitly all your variables like `str(result), str(data)`

Comment: thank you. The first does not work and I am not sure what you mean by typecasting in the second suggestion. Sorry.

Comment: my bad. I failed to see it is for `javascript`. You may try something like this: `string.concat(string1, string2, ..., stringX)` or the same logic can be applied as `var arr = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']; console.log(arr.join(',')); // 'a1,b1,c1'`. Explicit typecast can be done as `var price = ([String(result), String(data), String(symbol), String(quote), String(USD), String(price)]).join(".")`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

`string.concat(string1, string2, ..., stringX)`

or

`var arr = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']; 
console.log(arr.join(',')); // 'a1,b1,c1'.`

Explicit typecast can be done as,

`var price = ([String(result), String(data), String(symbol), String(quote), String(USD), String(price)]).join(".")`

Comment: thank you but how do I insert the variable "symbol" into either of these solutions. That is my difficulty. Not so much the concatenation. var arr = ['a1', 'a2', + symbol + , 'a3']?

Comment: returns error "data is not defined" data is a part of the json return.

Answer (score 0):

```
var price = result.data.BTC.quote.USD.price;
```

Should be replaced with a similar code that covers your variable name:

```
var price = result.data[symbol].quote.USD.price;
```